# Efficient way to find the difference between 2 IEnumerables

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> allInfo
```

and `IEnumerable<string> info1dim`. What is a way to find effectively the diff between `info1dim` and first dim of `allInfo`. For example :

```
allInfo = {<"data1", "addinfo1">, <"data2", "addinfo2">, <"data3", "addinfo3">"
```

and

```
info1dim = {"data3", "data1", "data4"}
```

The result I expect is

```
{"diff4"}
```

What is the most efficient way to do that?
I don't want to run two loops. The IEnumerables are huge (~100000 elements)

Comment: Assuming .NET has something similar to a Python `set`: Iterate the first enumerable and store all the keys in a set. Then iterate the second one and store them in another set. Now you can simply get the difference between the two sets (`a - b` and `b - a`) to find out which keys are only in the first/second enumerable.

Comment: "I don't want to run two loops" is an artificial requirement. Your problem *needs* iterating over *both* enumerables.

Comment: @OndrejTucny - you are right. let`s say - "i am looking for effective builtin approach"

Comment: I would seriously consider storing the data in a hashbased collection such as Dictionary<string, string> (as suggested in my answer). With that you have almost instant look up, and you only need to loop over the IEnumerable<string> once, you never actually loopthrough the dictionary.

Comment: If the two lists are sorted, you can use two index counter i & j (one for each list).  Then compare list1[i] and list2[j]. You  have three cases 1) list1[i] == list2[j].  item is in both lists. Increment I & j   1) list1[i] > list2[j]. item is in 2 and not 1.  Increment j not i. 2) list1[i] < list2[j] item is in 1 and not 2.  increment i not j.

Comment: How big a collection is info1dim compared to allInfo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C# HashSet collection has `ExceptWith`, `UnionWith`, and `IntersectWith` methods.  What you want could be done like this.

```
        var set1 = new HashSet<string>(allinfo.Select(t => t.Item1));
        var set2 = new HashSet<string>(info1dim);

        var set1_but_not_set2 = new HashSet<string>(set1);
        set1_but_not_set2.ExceptWith(set2);

        var set2_but_not_set1 = new HashSet<string>(set2);
        set2_but_not_set1.ExceptWith(set1);
```

Be careful, though, HashSet is a mutable collection and these functions change the collection.   You have `O(n)` operations here. Constructing the HashSet objects requires iterating; so do the `ExceptWith` operations.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a LINQ `Except()` like so:

```
info1dim.Except(allInfo.Select(i => i.Item1));
```

Note that `Except()` uses a `HashSet<T>` internally (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10269722/4832982)) so this is still O(n).

Comment: I need info1dim \ allInfo

Comment: Corrected (just reverse the statement).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
var diff = info1dim.Where(x => allInfo.Any(c => c.Item1 == x) == false);
```

If you store the `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>` in a `Dictionary<string,string>` instead it would become ALOT faster! then you could write:

```
Dictionary<string,string> allInfo;
IEnumerable<string> info1dim;
var diff = info1dim.Where(x => allInfo.ContainsKey(x) == false);
```

Answer (score 0):

load your info1dim in a HashSet and use Remove foreach item in allInfo :

```
// n: size of info1dim ; m: size of allInfo
var diff = new HashSet<string> (info1dim); // O(n)
foreach (var tuple in allInfo)  // O(m)
    diff.Remove (tuple.Item1);  // O(1)
```

*I didn't recall of `ExceptWith` existence before Ollie's answer ; after verifying at the [source reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,3abdc44f36894d3c) ExceptWith basically do the same (foreach -> Remove) and so should be better ; I keep my code as is as informative support tough*