# Refactor foreach and if's to Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Would it be possible to combine all the given code to linq, which then would return 'true' or 'false'? Or is this fine the way it is?

If it is possible, would there be a significant performance difference?(The array and list won't contain more than 100 elements)

```
foreach (var item in myArray)
{
    if (myList.Exists(x => x.Value == item))
    {
        amountTrue++;
    }
}

if (myArray.Count() == amountTrue)
{
    isValid = true;
}
```

Comment: Don't refactor for performance but readability and maintainability.

Comment: If you just need to know if all elements are in the list. Simply check in the loop if one element is not in the list then break.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I can see, the code is designed to check

> if all the items of the `myArray` are in the `myExists`

the implementation:

```
  isValid = myArray
    .All(item => myList.Exists(x => x.Value == item));
```

if you want to refactor for *performace* as well as for *readability*, have a look for bottlenecks. Say, is it `myList.Exists` that slows down? In that case think of `HashSet<T>` where `T` is a type of `x.Value` etc.

Comment: You have to be careful with LINQ's All() method. It's a vacuous truth statement. As a result isValid would end up being true if myArray were empty. Best to check to test if myArray is empty in addition to All(). #BattleScars

Comment: @Rafael Dowling Goodman: as I can see from your current code, if the array is empty then `amountTrue == 0` and thus `(myArray.Count() == amountTrue)` is `true`; my suggested refactoring does the same

Answer (score 7):

If I understand the problem, you want to know if all items in the array exist in the list:

```
bool isValid = !myArray.Except(myList.Select (l => l.Value )).Any();
```

Then this would be an efficient approach because `Except` uses a set and `Any` stops on the first missing.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko Solved it very efficient and easy to read. With your code you make it harder to understand what you are doing.

Comment: This is indeed the most efficient approach if only the `bool` result is needed. +1 (added an explanation)

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez Perhaps harder for the the untrained eye but more efficient. +1

Comment: Searching about Except impl I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269610/how-does-except-method-work-in-linq. So I have to upvote for the efficiency part (but not for the readability)

Answer (score 5):

Don't refactor for performance but readability and maintainability. But yes, there is a LINQ query which should be efficient *and* readable:

```
bool isValid = myArray.All(item => myList.Any(x => x.Value == item));
```

If you also need to know the count you have multiple options:

for example with `Enumerable.Any`:

```
int amountTrue = myArray.Count(item => myList.Any(x => x.Value == item));
```

or more efficient with a `HashSet<T>`, presuming `string`:

```
var uniqueValues = new HashSet<string>(myList.Select(x => x.Value));
int amountTrue = myArray.Count(uniqueValues.Contains);
```

Comment: You are doing too much work, see the @Dmitry Bychenko answer

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez: noticed it later, now i've provided multiple ways

Comment: I know, i just tell it to Tim. Now I find it's answer way better.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the LINQ implementation

```
var res = ((from z in myArray
            where myList.Exists(x=>x.Value=z)
            select z).Count())==myArray.Count()
```

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez the existence of a (in your opinion) slightly better answer is not a very good reason to down vote other good and correct answers.

Comment: The reason of the down vote wasn't the existing answer. It's the readability and performance, as he is doing more than need.